# How do I filter this array using value with handlebars.js?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/2.0.0/handlebars.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<!--This is our template. -->
<!--Data will be inserted in its according place, replacing the brackets.-->
<script id="t" type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#each_when profile "gender" "male"}}
        {{ID}}. {{from}} {{gender}}<br>
    {{/each_when}}
</script>

<!--Your new content will be displayed in here-->
<div class="content-placeholder"></div>

<script>
var json = {
    "profile": [
        { "ID": 1,  "gender": "male", "from": "Olivia" },
        { "ID": 2, "gender": "male", "from": "Meagen" },
        { "ID": 3,  "gender": "female, male",   "from": "Aaron" },
        { "ID": 4,  "gender": "female",   "from": "Aaron"  }
    ]
};

Handlebars.registerHelper('each_when', function(list, k, v, opts) {
    console.log(arguments);
    var i, result = '';
    for(i = 0; i < list.length; ++i)
        if(list[i][k] == v)
            result = result + opts.fn(list[i]);
    return result;
});

var t = Handlebars.compile($('#t').html());
$('body').append(t(json));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The result of the above code is:

```
1. Olivia male
2. Meagen male
```

But I want the following:

```
1. Olivia male
2. Meagen male
3. Aaron male
```

I am filtering an array of objects by a property and that property is a string that can contain multiple values.

Is there any one who can tell me why `3. Aaron male` is not appearing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object with the `ID` of `3` does not get appended to your result because your helper is filtering out objects whose `gender` property is NOT equal to `"male"`. Object 3's `gender` is `"female, male"`, so it does not pass the equality test.

If you want to check whether `list[i][k]` *contains* `v`, then you must update your logic.

```
var i, result = '', values;

for (i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
    values = list[i][k].replace(/\s*,\s*/, ',').split(',');
    if (values.indexOf(v) > -1) {
        result += opts.fn(list[i]);
    }
}

return result;
```

Note that I am using a regex to remove the white-space characters beside the "," before splitting - this way I can ensure that the elements in my `values` array do not begin or end with a space.

This update will append the "Aaron" object to the output. However, the final result will be:

```
1. Olivia male<br>
2. Meagen male<br>
3. Aaron female, male<br>
```

If you don't want "female, male" to display for Aaron that means you don't really want to render the object's `gender` property. Instead, you should just hard-code the text you want right into the template:

```
{{ID}}. {{from}} male<br>
```

Comment: Thanks '76484' for your reply. But your code not working.

Comment: @RehaanKkhaan: I had changed a few variable names when I wrote my solution. I have changed them back to your original `k` and `v`. For a working example see https://jsfiddle.net/zxm7x9sy/.